# What would cause KSMD to use CPU on a machine with no VMs?

Tags: centos, kvm-virtualization

I have a CentOS 6 machine that is used as a database (mysql) and application server.

Recently I've noticed that KSMD is waking up and using exactly a half a core for anywhere from a couple of minutes to several hours.

As near as I can tell, KSMD is only used on to do memory dedup for virtual machines.  The Documentation for this OS says: "A KSM cycle is triggered when the thres value added to the sum of all qemu-kvm processes RSZ exceeds total system memory."

I've checked, no VMs running on this machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that Linux's KSM implementation was originally intended for use with VMs, but as it can save memory on non-virtual systems, is deployed by default on CentOS 6 and later.

This server's memory usage has been creeping up and that apparently triggered KSMD to start scanning.

Somewhere along the line the documentation for CentOS 6 didn't get updated (or Google is linking me to an older version).  In addition, most of the links that I've found via Google queries still refers to KSM in the context of being exclusively used in KVM environments.